# Will users in unavailable territory get my app update

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

So I have an app that used to be available in 4 territories that is now available in only one.

I still have around 500 active users in the other 3 territories, but while thinking of a way to migrate these users, it just occurred to me that these users probably will not get the new app version if I release one.

The closest I have come to this information is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17).

Above refers to the status Removed from sale, my app is not "really" in that status, it's just removed from sale in some of the territories.

Has anyone tried this and have verified using analytics, or can find the documentation for this?

I'm sure if I activate the app in these 3 territories they will get the update, but I would prefer not to, since this will give me unintended downloads in these territories.

In time, all these users will stop using the app and then I will be able to remove the localized content from the source, but I would like to update the app in the meantime.

Thanks in advance.